# shell commands won't run in bash script

Tags: bash, sorting, awk, grep

I'm trying to pass a parameter to a bash script:
    "words.sh surf"

```
#!/bin/bash
#words.sh
#purpose:
#
#   to return a list of words 
#   sorted by the length of each word
# 
i=$1
cat ~/wordlist | grep $i | awk '{ print length(),$0 | "sort -n" }'
```

and I'm getting this message:

> usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoPqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]].
>
> awk: syntax error at source line 1
>
> context is.
>
> { print length(), >>>  -/bin/bash <<<  | "sort -n" }
>
> awk: illegal statement at source line 1

if I run the statement as a command :

```
cat ~/wordlist | grep surf | awk '{ print length(),$0 | "sort -n" }'
```

I get the correct output:

- ...
- ...
- 12 hypersurface
- 12 surfboarding
- 12 undersurface
- 12 unsurfeiting
- 13 subtersurface

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: can you post the contents of the file "wordlist"?

Comment: Seems to work for me. Are you sure you actually used single and not double quotes in the argument passed to awk?

Comment: I updated my comment to ask for the file (wordlist).

Comment: The reason I want the file is because I have created one of my own and I cannot reproduce the problem.  The best way to get help is provide all the information necessary for others to reproduce the issue.

Comment: wordlist -> /usr/share/dict/web2

Comment: I found out what the problem was.... I had an alias with the same name as the script. I removed the alias and the script worked. OOPS.Sorry for wasting your time folks :(

Answer (score 1):

You said it's working for you, but trust me it's got issues. Re-write it as:

```
awk -v i="$1" '$0 ~ i{print length(), $0 }' | sort -n
```